# TimeZone string formatting

Tags: go

How can I translate this code from Python to Go?

```
>>> from time import gmtime
>>> from time import strftime
>>> strftime("%z", gmtime())
'-0800'
```

I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Local().Format("-0700"))
}
```

But it's obviously not working:

```
+0000
```

I am somewhat confused in general about the formatting part of time because the const symbols (e.g. `stdNumTZ`) are not exported from the `time` package.

Is `time.Now().Local()` in Go the real substitute for `gmtime.gmtime()` in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `Local()` there since `time.Now()` returns local time. When I try to run your code on my machine, I get the correct result. It looks like the time zone where you're running this is UTC. (You can see the time zone by printing the result of `time.Now().Zone()`).

`gmtime` in Python returns UTC time. In Go, you can convert a time to UTC by calling `In(time.UTC)` on the time value. (I'm not a Python expert, and I don't know why the time zone of `gmtime()` is reported as the local time zone (I reproduced that on my machine).)

Comment: The time zone there is UTC, so that's why you're getting "+0000".